# When you move a new version of a dll to the GAC, will it be automatically updated in the running services?

Tags: .net, dll, windows-services, assemblies, gac

Or do I have to restart each service that uses it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would still have to restart the services.

Answer (score 0):

The services would have been loaded with the original version. In order to pick up the new version, a restart is required.